# Spring + @Transactional: can't rollback in case of error

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-orm

I am trying to implement the following: I need to add two different entities in same same transaction to database. 
I have different DAO classes and Service classes for each entity.

```
public class InvoicesDAO  {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(Invoice object) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

        session.persist(object);
    }
}

public class RequestsDAO {
    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(Request object) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, false);

        session.persist(object);
    }
}

public class InvoicesService {
    @Autowired
    private InvoicesDAO invoicesDAO;

    @Autowired
    private RequestsDAO requestsDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void add(Invoice object) throws HibernateException {
        invoicesDAO.save(object);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateAndGenerate(Invoice object1, Request object2) throws HibernateException {
        invoicesDAO.save(object1);
        requestsDAO.save(object2);
    }
}
```

The config:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/hibernate.properties" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}" />
        <property name="url" value="${hibernate.connection.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${hibernate.connection.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}" />
    </bean>      
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ejl.butler.object.data" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.cache.use_query_cache}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">${hibernate.cache.region.factory_class}</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.service" />
    <bean id="invoicesDao" class="com.dao.InvoicesDAO" />
<bean id="requestsDao" class="com.dao.RequestsDAO" />
```

Controller:

```
//***
/**
     * Invoices access service
     */
    @Autowired
    private InvoicesService invoicesService;

        // objects creation
        invoicesService.updateAndGenerate(invoice, request);
//***
```

So when I am trying to call updateAndGenerate method and pass there invalid values for object2 - it fails without rolling back the object1. How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: Are the daos and services Spring beans? How you call the method updateAndGenerate ?

Comment: How it fails, what exception is thrown? You can download the Spring sources(very easy with maven) and debug the code. I suspect that for some reason the transaction pointcut dont work, but I don't see anything wrong it what you have here.

Comment: It doesn't fails.. It should rollback but doesn't do it

Comment: The transaction will be rolled back only if some exception is thrown from your method.

Comment: Aaa, sorry, my mistake. I tried to catch all exceptions from Exception.class - same result. Another question - can it be because all my objects are not proxies? They are real objects?

Comment: If you create the object with new and not take it from the spring context it will not work. But you Autowire the service in the controller so that looks Ok. What do you mean by "real objects"?

Comment: Yes, I autowire service, but objects are new - not proxies.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43451/discussion-between-evgeny-and-nkognito)

Comment: none of this has anything to do with Spring MVC. changing tags

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I figured out where the problem was so I will answer my own question...

According to [Declarative transactions (@Transactional) doesn't work with @Repository in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9051721/705869) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250959/705869 the order of the `base-package` items inside `context:component-scan` directive is very important. In additional, you should put only really necessary packages.

I had some duplicates inside this directive so the application context was initialized before database context. And that's why transactions were disabled inside services!

So check twice for `base-package` packages inside `context:component-scan` and remove unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is got to do with Proxies. You dont need a proxy object here. Generally you need a proxy object for instances such for a login service etc where you need a proxy object for the singleton bean definition. But, the only way it can not rollback is if your propogation level on the Transaction isnt correct.

If you use a Trasaction.REQUIRES_NEW then the dao.save wouldnt rollback and it wouldnt tie back to the outer transaction and hence wouldnt rollback.